# Trying to test a factory and I am having injection issues

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, code-injection

I am rather new to angular and testing in general. I am trying to set up a basic test where I see if the object is defined before I start trying to test anything else.

I am getting this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateParamsProvider <-
>   $stateParams <- Form

However when I try and do this basic test on other test files this error does not show up.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('omnibyte_inspect_web.objects')
.factory('CommonQuestions', ['common_questions_factory', 'Form', '$rootScope',
    function (common_questions_factory, Form, $rootScope) {
    // Ctor
    function CommonQuestions(data) {
        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            this[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
        }
    };

    CommonQuestions.prototype.Select = function () {
        this.Id = guid();

        Form.CurrentForm().AddCommonQuestion(angular.copy(this));
    };
    CommonQuestions.prototype.Remove = function () {
        common_questions_factory.delete(this.Id).then(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };

        // Static Methods
    CommonQuestions.Current = function () {
        return $rootScope.config_info;
    };
    CommonQuestions.GetAll = function (callback) {
        common_questions_factory.get().then(function (data) {
            var collection = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                collection.push(new CommonQuestions(data[i]));
            }

            callback(collection);
        });
    };

    return CommonQuestions;
}]);
```

**Test File**

```
    describe('CommonQuestions Test', function () {
    beforeEach(module('omnibyte_inspect_web.objects'));

    var common_questions_factory, $rootScope, CommonQuestions, Form;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_common_questions_factory_, _Form_, _$rootScope_, _CommonQuestions_) {
        common_questions_factory = _common_questions_factory_;
        Form = _Form_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        CommonQuestions = _CommonQuestions_;

        spyOn(CommonQuestions, 'GetAll');
        spyOn(common_questions_factory, 'get');
        spyOn(CommonQuestions, 'Current');       
    }));

    it('should have CommonQuestions be defined', function () {
        expect(CommonQuestions).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**Edit**

Having the same issue on multiple files, but it seems to be coming from my Form file. Which is:

**Form**

```
angular.module('omnibyte_inspect_web.objects')
.factory('Form', ['forms_factory', 'authentication_service', 'common_questions_factory', 'formdata_factory', 'missinginformation_factory', '$stateParams', 'Question', 'LocationContact', '$rootScope', '$ionicPopup', '$state',
function (forms_factory, authentication_service, common_questions_factory, formdata_factory, missinginformation_factory, $stateParams, Question, LocationContact, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $state) {
```

**Second Edit**

After putting this module `beforeEach(module('ui.router'));` in my test file I get:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicPopupProvider <-
>   $ionicPopup <- Form

After putting this module `beforeEach(module('$ionic'));` in my test file I get the errors to go away; however, I get Expected undefined to be defined. This test has worked in all of my other files.

Comment: Please don't add "solved". Accept the answer that fixed the issue, this can be yours

Comment: Sounds good thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stateParams` is a service in angular-ui/ui-router. make sure ui-router is included in your karma.conf.js files.

Comment: This has been included in the karma file and I am still getting the error. Is this the right file? 

'www/lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js',

Comment: Added a few edits, hopefully this helps a little bit. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Solved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I needed to add these modules to the test file:

```
beforeEach(module('omnibyte_inspect_web.objects'));
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
beforeEach(module('ionic'));
```

And in my karma.conf.js file this was commented out:

```
'www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
```

After making those changes it was fixed.

Comment: good job! jasmine injection errors will usually be found somewhere there. stupidly hard to debug tho

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.